# Firing multiple actions on catch error

Tags: redux-observable

I am struggling to figure out how to fire multiple actions in a `catch` error handler in my epics.

I have successfully figured out how to fire multiple actions on a successful async call in my epics using the thunk-middleware. See below:

```
const editDomainsEpic = (action$) =>
  action$
    .ofType(EDIT_DOMAINS)
    .mergeMap((action) =>
      Rx.Observable.fromPromise(api.editDomains(action.payload))
        // Here we are using Redux thunk middleware to execute
        // a function instead of just dispatching an action
        // so that we can disptach two actions
        // ----------------- vvv
        .map((domain) => (dispatch) => {
          // Display Growl Notifications
          dispatch(
            displayGrowlNotification(
              MESSAGE_TYPES.SUCCESS,
              `${domain.name} was saved`
            )
          )
          // Fire Success Action
          dispatch({
            type: EDIT_DOMAINS_SUCCESS,
            payload: { domain }
          })
        })
        .catch((error) => Rx.Observable.of({
          type: EDIT_DOMAINS_ERROR,
          payload: { error }
        }))
        .takeUntil(action$.ofType(EDIT_DOMAINS_CANCEL))
    )
```

Can anyone guide me to how I can have the `catch` return or fire two observable actions that will get dispatched similarly to how I did with the success?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`Observable.of()` supports an arbitrary number of arguments and will emit them all sequentially one after the other, so to emit more than one action in your `catch`, you just add more arguments.

With that knowledge at hand, you can also use it to dispatch multiple actions for success instead of emitting a thunk and imperatively calling dispatch yourself.

```
const editDomainsEpic = (action$) =>
  action$
    .ofType(EDIT_DOMAINS)
    .mergeMap((action) =>
      Rx.Observable.fromPromise(api.editDomains(action.payload))
        .mergeMap((domain) => Rx.Observable.of(
          displayGrowlNotification(
            MESSAGE_TYPES.SUCCESS,
            `${domain.name} was saved`
          ), {
            type: EDIT_DOMAINS_SUCCESS,
            payload: { domain }
          }
        ))
        .catch((error) => Rx.Observable.of({
          type: EDIT_DOMAINS_ERROR,
          payload: { error }
        }, {
          type: ANOTHER_ONE,
          payload: 'something-else'
        }))
        .takeUntil(action$.ofType(EDIT_DOMAINS_CANCEL))
    )
```

This would be more idiomatic RxJS (and thus redux-observable) but it's not necessarily a requirement.

Comment: Awesome! Thanks! I am still a bit noob to RxJS, so learning these idoms is great